# NoSQL design for Owner 1:M PC and PC 1:M Parts

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Relationships:

- Owner 1:M PC
- PC 1:M Parts

In a traditional relational schema we have an Owner of a PC and then each PC can be made up of many parts.

Tables:

```
Parts
PC
PCParts
Owner
```

What is the MongoDB NoSQL data model for this?

Would the PC just contain an array of Part keys?

Comment: You need to provide more context. For example, if this is for an overclocker's forum and you don't care much about machine readability, parts could just be a bunch of strings. If, however, you want to *know* what they are, they'd have to have their own collection of "all known pc parts". So, what are you up to?

Comment: "PC 1:M Parts" "each PC can be made up of many parts" But also presumably each part can help make up many PCs. So PC M:M Parts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One solution would be to store an Owner document with one field consisting of a list of objectid references to PC documents.  Likewise, PC documents would include a list of objectid references to Parts documents.

This is the way MongoDB simulates relationships.  Think of an SQL foreign key, which resides in the child and references the parent, and **reverse the direction of reference**:  MongoDB stores in a parent document a list of objectid's for its children.

But this is not normalization -- it's *denormalization*.  It's like storing a comma-separated list of id's in an RDBMS, which would be a [repeating group that breaks First Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Repeating_groups_within_columns).

You might reasonably wonder how you would find out which PC's contain a given part, if the references are stored in the PC documents.  For that, you'd have to store a redundant list of reference to PC's in the Part document, and then worry about how you're going to keep the bidirectional references in sync, risking anomalies where a PC thinks it uses a Part, but that respective Part has no reference to the PC (or vice versa).

You could create a MongoDB document mimicking an SQL many-to-many intersection table, where one document contains exactly one objectid reference to a PC and one reference to a Part.  Then create many such documents, as you would create many rows in an intersection table in SQL.  But because these are documents, not rows, there's no schema to enforce that all documents store only the one reference for each entity.  And there's no such thing as a JOIN to do the lookup efficiently.

These are consequences of denormalization and document-oriented databases, and why relational databases still offer some advantages.

Comment: "You might reasonably wonder how you would find out which PC's contain a given part" -- why not simply index the embedded collection and query it, instead of keeping two collections in sync? I never had to do that. Moreover, I'd not store _only_ the ID in your list of parts: Always store the id and some additional info (like description) you typically want to display - otherwise, you'll need a join when displaying the list.

Comment: "why not simply index the embedded collection and query it"?  Sure, you could avoid storing redundantly, but wouldn't that incur an index scan, versus just getting the list from the Part document (which you presumably already have)?

Comment: What does the list of the *IDs* of PCs that contain a given part help? Presumably, you need to fetch the associated PCs anyway. Hence you're better off using the Multikey feature, which employs indexing. But the key issue about this question remains: the OP hasn't stated what he's trying to *accomplish*.

Comment: Exactly.  Database design in a non-relational database like MongoDB depends on the *queries you need to support*, not the relationships between data entities.